# Meteor: calling function from Meteor.methods

Tags: methods, meteor, call

At first I would like to notice that I'm beginner in Meteor. I don't know why this code:

```
Meteor.methods =
  fun: ->
    "This is message."

if Meteor.isClient
  Template.hello.greeting = ->
    "Welcome to FirstApp."

  Template.hello.events =
    "click input": ->
       console.log "You pressed the button."
```

when this line typed in browser console:

```
Meteor.call("fun", function(err, res) { if(err) alert(err); else alert(res); });
```

allerts: Error: Method not found [404] instead of "This is message.".
Why fun is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `Meteor.methods` should not be assigned to a function. if you do it like that, you will ever have only one function.

Try this instead:

```
if Meteor.isServer
   Meteor.methods({
      fun: ->
         "This is message."
   })
```

I am not aware that coffeescript can be used on the client. But your definition is wrong as the events is an object with multiple functions

this is correct (provided coffeescript works on the client):

```
Template.hello.events({
   "click input": ->
      console.log "You pressed the button."
})
```

have fun with Meteor and read the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com)

Answer (score 1):

Did you put this file in the `client` directory? `Meteor.methods` has to define `fun` on the server in order for the callback to be triggered properly.

The client version of `Meteor.methods` only defines a local stub.